# How to call sendMFACode function from out of the authenticateUser in aws cognito

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, amazon-cognito-identity-js

How to call the `sendMFACode` function from out of the `authenticateUser` function in the AWS cognito for node js rest API.

When I executing the `cognitoUser.sendMFACode`. I get the following error:

```
{ code: 'InvalidParameterException',
  name: 'InvalidParameterException',
  message: 'Missing required parameter Session' }
```

The executed code is

```
cognitoUser.sendMFACode('123456', {
                onSuccess: function (result) {
                   console.log(result);
                },
                onFailure: function (err) {
                   console.log(err);
                }
            })
```

`cognitoUser.getSession()` works only for authenticated user

> Error: Missing required parameter Session